# Sample larger than population or is negative from random sample to prepare training and test sets

Tags: python, random

```
class_names = ['Normal', 'Viral Pneumonia', 'COVID','Lung_Opacity']
root_dir = 'COVID-19_Radiography_Dataset'
source_dirs = ['Normal', 'Viral Pneumonia', 'COVID','Lung_Opacity']

if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_dir, source_dirs[1])):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test2'))

    for i, d in enumerate(source_dirs):
        os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, d), os.path.join(root_dir, class_names[i]))

    for c in class_names:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test2', c))

    for c in class_names:
        images = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, c)) if x.lower().endswith('png')]
        selected_images = random.sample(images,30)
        for image in selected_images:
            source_path = os.path.join(root_dir, c, image)
            target_path = os.path.join(root_dir, 'test', c, image)
            shutil.move(source_path, target_path)
```

**Error Meaasge**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 5>()
     14 for c in class_names:
     15     images = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, c)) if x.lower().endswith('png')]
---> 16     selected_images = random.sample(images, 30)
     17     for image in selected_images:
     18         source_path = os.path.join(root_dir, c, image)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py:482, in Random.sample(self, population, k, counts)
    480 randbelow = self._randbelow
    481 if not 0 <= k <= n:
--> 482     raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    483 result = [None] * k
    484 setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list

ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How To Fix this "Sample larger than population or is negative" message. Was going through the dataset COVID-19 Radiography Database and Wanted to prepare training and test sets.

Comment: As per the doc [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) `If the sample size is larger than the population size, a ValueError is raised.` In your case make your `k=30` be less than images.

Comment: A simple example to reproduce the error:
`print(random.sample(range(10),11))`

Comment: same error though i changed my sample size